# Firestore rules, how can I limit output if creator or invited is equal to my id?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following data.

[image]

I tried to do something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
match /dialogs/{documentId}{
   allow read,update, delete: if isCreator() || isInvited();

   function isCreator() {
      return resource.data.creator == request.auth.uid;
   }
      function isInvited() {
      return resource.data.invited == request.auth.uid;
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you do to get to the conclusion that it doesn't work? Your rules should work.

Comment: Please edit your question to also show the minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Security rules don't have much meaning without specific client queries they are designed to allow or reject.  Please edit the question to show the queries that aren't working the way you expect with these rules.  We should be able to duplicate the situation on our own using the information in your question.